# How to replace an existing picture in Picture Content Control in Word 2013+ using Interop C# or VB

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I'm using Word 2013. I go to Developer Tab, add a "Picture Content Control" to my document. Set its title as "logo". Then, click on the control and set a default image.

My question is how to replace that default image by any other image using Word Interop (not OpenXML please), language can be C# or VB doesn't matter.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

ContentControls controls = d.SelectContentControlsByTitle("logo");
foreach (ContentControl c in controls)
{
    if (c.Type == WdContentControlType.wdContentControlPicture)
    {                        
        // ContentControl of Interop.Word doesn't have Image property
        // Couldn't cast the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.PictureContentControl either
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code we'd love to help!!

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Try this: Not really an answer, but they seem to be doing exactly what you need.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398971.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can replace picture like this,

```
ContentControls controls = doc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("logo");

foreach (ContentControl contentControl in controls)
{
    var cc = contentControl.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("imageLocation");
}
```

Comment: my code doesn't work this way, is there another way?